# Incorrect instancing Collection Instance on mirrored faces

Tags: mirror, collections, instances

I'm modeling mechanical bird wings. The workflow until now was:

1. Collection of feather parts
2. Instance Collection
3. Make a Plane, added Array -> Curve (linked to Bezier curve) -> Mirror (linked to Empty)
4. Link Instance Collection as a child to parent Plane, enabled instancing on Faces on Plane

Result - as you can see, left side is correct, right side is incorrect and I don't know why, nor how to fix it.
[image: incorrect instancing on mirrored faces]

I've made a simplified .blend file if someone would like to poke personally (just a small note, Collection Instance "FeatherInstance", is hidden in viewport)

[image]